# Why is my decimal to binary program adding extra numbers to the end?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I'm writing a program that takes an integer named decimalInput (currently a literal for testing purposes) and converts it to a String called binaryOutput, which is the decimal number in binary form. I'm using [this guide (the first one)](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary) to explain how the conversion from decimal to binary is done. Here's my code so far:

```
public class ToBin {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int decimalInput = 19070;
    String binaryOutput = "";
    while (decimalInput > 0) {
        if (decimalInput % 2 == 0) {
            binaryOutput = "0" + binaryOutput;
            decimalInput = decimalInput / 2;
        }
        else {
            binaryOutput = "1" + binaryOutput;
            decimalInput = decimalInput / 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(binaryOutput);
    }
}
```

For the current literal I have (19070), my program returns the string "100101001111110". However, this is incorrect. My program SHOULD return "10010100111". So, for some reason my program has added an extra string of "1110" to the end. At first I thought, okay, maybe I goofed on the math somewhere. So I tried checking the math, it looked okay. Then I tried changing the literal decimalInput to a smaller number, specifically 156, which returns the string "10011100", which is the proper output.

I tried changing decimalInput to type long to see if that would help, but it didn't.

All I know is that for some reason, larger numbers are making my program flip out. And I don't know why.

I would greatly appreciate any help, as this is really frustrating me. This is also for a class, so as much as I would like to use toBinaryString(), I'm unable to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the bit shift operator instead of dividing by two
`decimalInput = decimalInput >> 1`

Comment: Since 2^11 = 2048 and 19070 > 4096 = 2^12, the binary representation of 19070 must contain at least 12 digits, which means that what you claim your program SHOULD do is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I would use toBinaryString to check your result all the same

```
int decimalInput = 19070;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(decimalInput));
```

prints

```
100101001111110
```

as does your program so its correct!

Note: your program won't display negative numbers at all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I just tried that, and it looks like you're right. Our instructor gave us a few examples for the different bases we were supposed to be able to convert between, and for the decimal function, apparently he gave us the wrong output we were supposed to be checking for. Using online base converters confirms this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you think of how to fix you program so it handles negative numbers?

Comment: @M_rk If you use signed shift, how do you know when to stop? ;)

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer the second question**

"Can you think of how to fix you program so it handles negative numbers?"

As I suggested in my other comment I would use the bit shift operator.

The if statement would become this:

`if (decimalInput & 0x01 == 0) { // If the least significant bit is set`

And the 'division' would become this:

`decimalInput = decimalInput >>> 1; // Shifting all bits one to the right`

This may help you with understanding what's going on:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: +1 Not sure its the OP's question, but a good answer.

Comment: Damn, I'm being stupid here.. :P

Comment: In that case you are in good company. LOL.